# Flutter - how to keep the state dynamically for Widgets inside Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `2 pages` (**Page A** and **Page B**) that you can navigate from and to via a `bottom navigation bar`.

I have a special use can where:

**Page A** : must be "`keptAlive`" most of the time, only 1 scenario where it should rebuild

**Page B**: must be `rebuilt` every time we switch to it.

I got these behaviors working but one, the `Dynamic` `keepAlive` for **Page A**.

First of all, the code:

**Main Page** that holds the navigation:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  PageController? _pageController;
  List<Widget> _pages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _currentIndex = 0;
    _pages = [PageA(), PageB()];

    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _currentIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('example')),
      body: PageView(
      controller: _pageController,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: _pages,
    ),
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar.builder(
        itemCount: _iconList.length,
        activeIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
            _pageController!.jumpToPage(index);
            });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now this part works fine, in **Page B** I don't need to do anything special, as by default with PageView, everytime I switch to that Page, it will rebuild.

Now, for **Page A**, I want that most of the time it DOESN'T rebuild if navigating from **Page B**

And I achieve this with: `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and `wantKeepAlive` :

**Page A widget:**

```
class PageA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageAState createState() => _PageAState();
}

class _PageAState extends State<PageA> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<PageA> {
 bool shouldKeepAlive = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => shouldKeepAlive;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    /// .....
```

So this works great, the **Page A** is not being rebuilt, but I have a special case,
where if in **Page A**, the user fills a `textField` with any value, and then switches to **Page B**, I want that if the user goes back to **Page A**, now it has been reset and rebuilt!

I tried different approaches, but I cannot change the value of `wantKeepAlive` once **Page A** has been built for the first time.
I tried using `updateKeepAlive()` but it doesn't help, so does someone have an idea, how I can dynamically set `wantKeepAlive` on **Page A**, so that if I navigate to **Page B** under some special conditions, when coming back to **Page A**, it might or might not be reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 'updateKeepAlive' method in 'AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin' class,
you can change keepAlive condition.

If user type some text at 'TextField' in the PageA,
set 'shouldKeepAlive' to false and call 'updateKeepAlive' method to update keep alive option.

I confirmed working well by pushing log message to build() method to confirm when build() is called.

-----Modification----
I don't know exactly why 'updateKeepAlive' is adapted after focusing is out from the TextField widget.
I changed some code to detach focus from TextField after keyboard is disappeared by using 'down arrow' or 'checkmark' button.
For this reason, I used one package to check whether keyboard is show or hide.
https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility

[image]

```
import 'package:animated_bottom_navigation_bar/animated_bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Example(),
    );
  }
}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  PageController _pageController;
  List<Widget> _pages = [];

  final iconList = <IconData>[
    Icons.brightness_5,
    Icons.brightness_4,
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _currentIndex = 0;
    _pages = [PageA(), PageB()];

    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _currentIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('example')),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: _pages,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar.builder(
        itemCount: 2,
        activeIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
            _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
          });
        },
        tabBuilder: (int index, bool isActive) {
          final color = isActive ? Color(0XFFFFA400) : Colors.grey;
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(
                iconList[index],
                size: 24,
                color: color,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 4),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                child: Text(
                  "Page $index",
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: TextStyle(color: color),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageAState createState() => _PageAState();
}

class _PageAState extends State<PageA>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<PageA> {
  bool shouldKeepAlive = true;
  String input;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
      onChange: (bool visible) {
        if (!visible) {
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
          print('keyboard disappeared');
          if (!shouldKeepAlive && input.isEmpty) {
            shouldKeepAlive = true;
            updateKeepAlive();
          } else if (shouldKeepAlive && input.isNotEmpty) {
            shouldKeepAlive = false;
            updateKeepAlive();
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => shouldKeepAlive;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    print('PageA is builded');

    return TextField(
      onSubmitted: (String value) {
        print('onSumitted: $value');
      },
      onChanged: (String value) {
        input = value;
        print('onChanged: $value');
      },
    );
  }
}

class PageB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageBState createState() => _PageBState();
}

class _PageBState extends State<PageB> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('PageB is builded');
    return TextField();
  }
}
```

Comment: This was my first approach after I found the "updateKeepAlive()" method, but it didn't work so I posted here, basically I have your exact same code, I have some prints in the "onChanged" method of the TextField, and the ShouldKeepAlive value is updated correctly, but even if "shouldKeepAlive" is set to false, if I switch to PageB, when I go back to PageA, I'm in the same exact state, TextField has what I wrote before switching pages and the page is not reset...something is missing, it seems that when I navigate back, it doesn't trigger to recreate the PageA widget

Comment: and I just run your code, and indeed, if you fill up the TextField in PageA, then switch to PageB, when you come back to PageA, even in your example, the TextField has still the value...so it didn't reset PageA

Comment: @AJ989 Really? I confirmed many times whether it works what you want.

Comment: @AJ989 I attached gif  I tested to content.

Comment: ok I found out why it doesn't work on my side, I was closing the keyboard with the "down arrow" instead of clicking the "checkmark icon" to close the keyboard.. This brings me to an issue, how can I make sure that even if the user closes the keyboard with the "down" button, and switches page, I have the same behavior? Thanks for the help

Comment: @AJ989 I don't know root cause of 'updateKeepAlive' working difference between using 'down arrow' and 'checkmark icon'. But I found that after focus is detached from TextField affect the result. So, I changed code. Please check again

Comment: great, these changes achieve exactly what I need! thank you for the support, I was so close to the solution, but using the "arrow-down" key threw me off, thinking that        updateKeepAlive(); wasn't working as intended! many thanks